# timeval not returning expecting results

Tags: c++, timeval, time.h

I have some code shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

typedef struct{
     struct timeval timestamp;
}teststruct;

class TestClass {
     public:
       TestClass();
       void dosomething(int, int);
};

TestClass::TestClass(){
}

void
TestClass::dosomething(int num, int numb) {
}

int main(void){
     TestClass *testclass = new TestClass();
     teststruct test;
     gettimeofday(&test.timestamp, NULL);
     printf("%llu \n", test.timestamp.tv_sec);
     testclass->dosomething(1,1);
     printf("%llu \n", test.timestamp.tv_sec);
}
```

The output of this code is:

13825459612132795564 
dosomething
5598307500

but I have no idea why the first number is messed up.  Also the class call is completely necessary in order for the numbers to be different from one another.

Comment: why did you wrap up the timeval variable into a typedef'd struct?

Answer (score 4):

I get `warning: format ‘%llu’ expects type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘__time_t’`. Should be a hint. Up your compiler's warning level to something sensible.

It [works](http://www.ideone.com/0gaZV) when you use the proper input type. You were invoking UB otherwise, reading memory that wasn't yours to read; bugs like this can yield funny results that behave differently based on factors that you wouldn't normally expect to make a difference, as the contents of your memory change.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work if you change the `%llu` to `%lu`.

http://codepad.org/YGubabLR